# Как реализовать проброс порта на C#?

Tags: c#

Пытался реализовать проброс порта, но остановился на этом шаге и не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
UPnPNATClass upnpnat = new UPnPNATClass();
IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection; // Выбрасывает null
```

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте, что на роутере включен UPNP и что у вас есть нужные права. Скорее всего проблема в этом.

Также поговаривают, что если вы используете .NET 4.0 и выше, то может помочь добавление этой секции в app.config:

```
<startup uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy="true">
```

Ну и если ничего не поможет, можете попробовать [Open.NAT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/807861/Open-NAT-A-NAT-Traversal-library-for-NET-and-Mono).

Comment: На роутере настройки UPNP вообще нет. 
Попробовал Open.NAT, вот результат -> https://yadi.sk/i/x9bGR1xUpf4Jk
Зашел на сайт, который там предложен, проверил и ошибка, не видит меня. Попробовал на всякий случай все порты от 1600 - 1603 и от 1700 до 1703

Comment: @testermatrix так может ваш роутер вообще не поддерживает UPNP/порт форвардинг?

Comment: Как это точно  можно определить? И может есть какие-то другие варианты,  чтобы установить соединение для обмена сообщениями в интернете между двумя компьютерами с известными внешними динамическими адресами на c#?

Comment: @testermatrix увы не знаю.